# How do I use dnspython to query for a host pattern

Tags: python, dnspython

Let us say that I want to count the number of hosts that match a simple pattern.  For example:

host1.example.com
host2.example.com
...
host42.example.com

where I don't know ahead of time that there are 42 of these.  What I would like to do is something like:

```
answers = dns.resolver.query('host*.example.com', 'A')
```

and then be able to get the length of answers for the count or iterate over answers for the actual hostnames.

Thanks,

Glenn

Comment: Any library to enable DNS lookups is unlikely to implement such a feature, since this could easily result in a massive amount of DNS queries, which are often limited by registrars / WHOIS servers. You need to implement this yourself by creating a list of hostnames and looping over them.

Comment: Or in other words: DNS does not support or allow any sort of wildcard queries. Without knowing the exact hostname to query for in advance, there's no way of discovering records, short of a zone transfer.

Comment: Effectively, that's what I wound up doing: dumping the xfr into a local file or a dict and greping/iterating over that.

Comment: Oh, you're allowed to do zone transfers? Yeah, then that's probably the way to go.